# Изменения даты комментария

Tags: javascript

Есть блог на базе Блогспот.
Дата комментария задается параметром `<data:comment.timestamp/>`

Можно ли как-то написать скрипт, который будет изменять дату комментария в определенных границах, например, с 20.09.2011 по 20.10.2011?

Comment: Ну я с Блогспотом только поверхностно знаком...Он от гугла...И там база своя...Скорей всего нельзя...Точно не скажу поэтому "комент" :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

думаю нет потому что дата берется из БД. а к бд доступа нет, может и есть какие-нибудь инструменты напрямую править код своего блога. на счет скрипта - написать то можно, вот только дата измениться только у Вас :)